# What software and programming languages do i need to create an app?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in regards to software development(I usually do website building). I have heard certain app have work on different engines but i just kindly like to be know what to download.

Comment: When it comes to Android, Android Studio is basically everything you need, since SDK's and emulators will be downloaded within the wizard ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your previous knowledge of programming.

If you have none, I strongly suggest you to first learn java and after that start android.

The best place to learn how to start programming for android is https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html which teaches you build your first app.

For building apps in java for android you'll need:

- [Android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)
- Android SDK (Android studio will download it for you)

Then you are all set to write your first app.

Of course You can create android apps with other programming languages as well. but mostly java is first choice when it comes to android.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to add i recommend using https://www.codecademy.com to learn java.

Comment: Your welcome. Yes codecademy is very good.

Answer (score 1):

For Android apps, you need to know Java or Kotlin language. Download Android Studio to start building apps.

Comment: Java or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

As you have android tag I presume that you are interested in Android development.
So you need IDE: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html and language: Java

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need Android Studio [Download](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Learn the basics from here [Android Training](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) and build your first app

You need to Learn Java too !!!

**Happy Coding Bro :)**

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at those udacity courses:
https://www.udacity.com/courses/android